# Is there any good use for a default Java class (i.e. non-public, non-abstract, non-final, subclass of Object)

Tags: java, class, oop, design-patterns

I've been programming in C and C++ for a few years and am taking some Java classes for the first time.  I've come across the chapter on Java classes and am curious about the default declaration for a Java class:

class Myclass {

//Vars and Methods

}

This compiles I'm told, but does it have any practical usage, such as in any particular design patterns or applications?

If it matters, this is for Java 6.  Old, I know, but a project at work is built on Java6 and that's what is motivating me to learn this.

Comment: Um, yes - it's perfectly useful to create a class which is an implementation detail of a particular package (and so shouldn't be exposed publicly). Why would it *not* be useful?

Comment: One of the saddest things about how OO languages are taught is the lack of practical examples for different levels of access control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default access in Java is package private. This means the class is visible only to other classes in the same package.

It is useful, for example, if you write a library and want to prevent users of your library from directly using internal classes that are not part of your API. This allows you to change those internal classes in later versions without having to worry about backward compatibility.

Comment: The default is package protected, not private.

Comment: @markbernard There is no such thing package protected. There's public, protected, package private (which is the default) and private.

Answer (score 1):

This is useful when you want other classes **in the same package only** to have access to this class and is good practise to limit the number of public classes visible from a package.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no visibility identifier that is known as default or package private. The typical use for this would be with a factory object. You expose the factory and the interface it uses publicly but keep the class as default so they cannot be "new"ed outside of the package. This will restrict their use to be exclusively through the factory.

```
package pac1.pac2;

public class Factory {
  public FactoryInterface createObject() {
  }
}

package pac1.pac2;

public interface FactoryInterface {
  public void doWork();
}

package pac1.pac2;

class FactoryImpl1 implements FactoryInterface {
  public void doWork() {
    //doing work
  }
}
```

This is really simplistic but the idea is that you can create objects of the provided interface using influences outside of code such as properties or configuration files. So you can have multiple implementations of the `FactoryInterface` and make decisions about which ones to use at run time instead of compile time.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually uses for it.

Consider following package

```
com.company.modulename.MainEntryPointForModule
com.company.modulename.Class1
com.company.modulename.Class2
```

When Class1 and Class2 are used only inside MainEntryPointForModule it makes sense to make them default. This design rule can actually decrease amount of mess in reasonably big project.

Answer (score 0):

Package private (default) is useful for [Simple Factory](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716413/Factory-Method-Pattern-vs-Abstract-Factory-Pattern) when you don't want Clients to access the concrete products. It provides access control, or a kind of encapsulation, at the package level.

In the following example in UML, Client can't see the Circle/Rectangle/Polygon classes, because they're package-protected. Client *can* see a Shape, however. The ShapeFactory will allow the Client to obtain instances of the concrete Shape classes without knowing their details. This is classic information hiding.

[image: Simple factory with package visibility of concrete classes]

It's analogous to a class having public/private members. In this case, the package has public "members" ShapeFactory and Shape, and private "members" Circle, Rectangle, Polygon.